# Xamarin Multiplaform UWP won't build with error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin multi-platform project Android/iOS/UWP. All 3 projects have compiled properly over the past year. Then a few weeks ago the UWP project would not compile with the following Error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Loading assembly "C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.14\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Thread.dll" failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly element)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadAssemblyResources(String name, String outFileOrDir)
```

In fact I got a total of 20 errors. 10 of the above error and 10 of these (I suspect they are related to each other):

```
Error       Invalid Resx file. String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: suffix  Mobile.UWP  C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.14\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Private.Uri.dll
```

I have been searching for nearly 3 weeks and not finding any solutions. I find lots of information but nothing that points to a solution.
I'm using VS 2020 with the following versions:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.5.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.5+33627.172
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual C++ 2022   00476-80000-00000-AA235
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.5.320.55692
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.5.320.55692
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.5.320.55692
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.22336.2
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Entity Framework Core Power Tools   2.5
Adds useful design-time EF Core DbContext features to the Visual Studio Solution Explorer context menu.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.3 (main@2a4517a)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.5.9 (11975e6)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

Node.js Tools   1.5.50105.3 Commit Hash:882de61a7c99ae988d4c62029301292a3e0b1d56
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.22336.2
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.22336.2
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.5.2.2316603+9f1b6856460af1e592d387ebef416eadddac453f
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.40120.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20105.2003
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.5.0-beta.23053.5+794b7c259d9646a7eb685dad865aa27da7940a21
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.5.0.173 (d17-5@33e727c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.5.3.46 (remotes/origin/d17-5@e4dd80b2bb)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.5.41 (ba80d05)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.0 (d17-5/797e2e1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.0@fdc1e34
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.2.0.5 (7738c90c9)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Another developer in the office does not have the same problem and can compile just fine. However we cannot seem to find any differences between out computers.
I'm looking for solutions as I have read many Microsoft articles & FAQs and notices but none seem to lead to a solution.